# How to slow down move planet in its orbit?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation, graphics

I have a model of planet (below) and paint the Sun in center of screen. Then I draw the planets using a new thread. Planets move is too fast and not means that it's a move on a circle. I tried to change the thread's sleep time and planet's velocity and does not matter - planets move too fast. Velocity > 3 - too fast speed.

I need result: Planets move slow and I can manage a planet's speed with her velocity (1, 3, 5, 10). Angle (position of planet) changes 1 time in second on small amount (1, 3, 5 degrees - velocity)

```
public class Planet
{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private double radius = 1.0;
    private double radiusOrbit = 5.0;
    private double velocity = 1;
    private Color color;
    private int angle = 0;
    private String parent;

    public Planet(String name, int id, double rad, double radOrbit, double velocity, Color color)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.radius = rad;
        this.radiusOrbit = radOrbit;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.color = color;
   }
...getters and setters
}
```

Main Class

```
public class ShowCosmos2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new PlanetsFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PlanetsFrame extends JFrame
{

    private int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    private int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    public PlanetsFrame()
    {
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle("Planets");

        setContentPane(new PlanetsCanvas(width, height));
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}

class PlanetsCanvas extends JPanel
{
    private int width, height;
    private int centerX = 0;
    private int centerY = 0;
    private Thread runner;
    private boolean running = false;
    Planet[] planets = {
        new Planet("Venera", 1, 5.0, 50.0, 1, Color.GREEN),
        new Planet("Mercury", 1, 3.0, 75.0, 1.5, Color.ORANGE),
        new Planet("Earth", 1, 6.0, 100.0, 2, Color.BLUE),
        new Planet("Jupiter", 1, 12.0, 150.0, 1, Color.RED)
    };
    public PlanetsCanvas(int w, int h)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        centerX = (int)(w/2);
        centerY = (int)(h/2);
    }

    protected void drawFrame(Graphics g)
    {
        //Sun
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(width/2 - 25, height/2 - 25, 50, 50);
            for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++)
            {
                Planet p = planets[i];
                g.setColor(p.getColor());
                int newX = (int)(centerX + Math.cos(p.getAngle())*p.getRadiusOrbit());
                int newY = (int)(centerY - Math.sin(p.getAngle())*p.getRadiusOrbit());
                g.fillOval((int)(newX-p.getRadius()),
                        (int)(newY-p.getRadius()), 
                        (int)p.getRadius()*2, (int)p.getRadius()*2);
                //int angle = (int)(p.getAngle() + p.getVelocity());
                //if (angle >= 360) angle = 0;
                //p.setAngle(angle);
            }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawFrame(g);
        startAnimation();
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        runner = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        repaint();
                        for(int i=0; i<planets.length; i++)
                        {
                            Planet p = planets[i];
                            int angle = (int)(p.getAngle() + p.getVelocity());
                            if (angle >= 360) angle = 0;
                            p.setAngle(angle);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        runner.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most important -- don't start your animation from within paintComponent. The paintcomponent method will keep being called over and over again, meaning you're going to be creating more and more animation threads unnecessarily, when only one is what's called for. What's worse, you do not have complete control over when or even if paintComponent is called. So instead start your animation thread once and likely in your class's constructor.

Comment: Good. How I can to paint this without paintComponent? I tryed to do this without paintComponent - I see the empty black screen.. startAnimation() I moved to a constructor.

Comment: @JAgeev: you still need to use paintComponent to do your drawing for you, but that's all it should be doing. It should have no code that starts threads or  timers, and it should have no code that changes the state of the object, only that changes the component's appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider following points

1. Your `startAnimation()` method should be called once only and not in `paintComponent()` method which will instantiate a new thread on every `repaint()`
2. Apart from that keep the `angle` a double type as this will allow you to make arbitrarily small increments and decrements to it.
3. `Thead.sleep()` interval should be the single frame time.
4. Maintain a `DAMPING_COFFICIENT` to multiply to `velocity` when calculating new `angle` to slow down or speed up.

Here's modified slowed down code.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Planet {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private double radius = 1.0;
    private double radiusOrbit = 5.0;
    private double velocity = 1;
    private Color color;
    private double angle = 0;
    private String parent;

    public Planet(String name, int id, double rad, double radOrbit,
            double velocity, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.radius = rad;
        this.radiusOrbit = radOrbit;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadiusOrbit() {
        return radiusOrbit;
    }

    public void setRadiusOrbit(double radiusOrbit) {
        this.radiusOrbit = radiusOrbit;
    }

    public double getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public void setVelocity(double velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(String parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public double getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(double angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

Rest of the classes

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ShowCosmos2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new PlanetsFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PlanetsFrame extends JFrame {

    private int width = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    private int height = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

    public PlanetsFrame() {
        setSize(width, height);
        setTitle("Planets");

        setContentPane(new PlanetsCanvas(width, height));
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
}

class PlanetsCanvas extends JPanel {
    private static final double DAMPING_COFFICIENT = 0.01;
    private static final int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
    private static final long FRAME_DURATION = (1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND);

    private int width, height;
    private int centerX = 0;
    private int centerY = 0;
    private Thread runner;
    private boolean running = false;
    Planet[] planets = { new Planet("Venera", 1, 5.0, 50.0, 1, Color.GREEN),
            new Planet("Mercury", 1, 3.0, 75.0, 1.5, Color.ORANGE),
            new Planet("Earth", 1, 6.0, 100.0, 2, Color.BLUE),
            new Planet("Jupiter", 1, 12.0, 150.0, 1, Color.RED) };

    public PlanetsCanvas(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        centerX = (int) (w / 2);
        centerY = (int) (h / 2);
        startAnimation();
    }

    protected void drawFrame(Graphics g) {
        // Sun
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(width / 2 - 25, height / 2 - 25, 50, 50);
        for (int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
            Planet p = planets[i];
            g.setColor(p.getColor());
            int newX = (int) (centerX + Math.cos(p.getAngle())
                    * p.getRadiusOrbit());
            int newY = (int) (centerY - Math.sin(p.getAngle())
                    * p.getRadiusOrbit());
            g.fillOval((int) (newX - p.getRadius()),
                    (int) (newY - p.getRadius()), (int) p.getRadius() * 2,
                    (int) p.getRadius() * 2);
            // int angle = (int)(p.getAngle() + p.getVelocity());
            // if (angle >= 360) angle = 0;
            // p.setAngle(angle);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawFrame(g);
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        runner = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        repaint();
                        for (Planet p : planets) {
                            double angle = (p.getAngle() + p.getVelocity() * DAMPING_COFFICIENT);

                            //System.out.println(p.getName() + " : " + angle);

                            if (angle >= 360)
                                angle = 0;
                            p.setAngle(angle);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(FRAME_DURATION);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        runner.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
```

.